# key-value MySQL Table self join

Tags: mysql, database, key-value-store

I have a MySQL database that has three tables , the three tables are like that :

> DATA_TRANSACTION(ID_TRANSACTION,ID_USER,TRANSACTION_NAME)
>
> DATA_DICT(ID_KEY,NAME_KEY)
>
> DATA_TABLE(ROW_NUMBER,ID_TRANSACTION,KEY,VALUE)

Data_table is a key-value table , and all keys are in the DATA_DICT .

DATA_TABLE looks like this :

```
ROW | ID_TRANSACTION | KEY | VALUE
--------------------------------- 
1   | 154           |Name   |Robert 
2   | 154           |Power1 |54 
3   | 265           |Name   |John 
4   | 265           |Place  |Dallas
```

I want to extract all Ids where name = John and power1 =58 by **self joining** the table .

I already have an equivalent query , that returns the same result :

`SELECT ID_TRANSACTION FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE KEY='Name' AND VALUE = 'John' AND ID_TRANSACTION IN (SELECT ID_TRANSACTION FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE KEY='POWER 1' AND VALUE= 54);`

And how the query looks like if we have more than 2 criteria.

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Comment: EAV Models like this are notoriously hard to do the type of querying you are doing. :(

Comment: Luckily, the situation never arises, which makes things easier